# what is the best way to return something

Tags: java, performance, formatting

if i have a function that return something what is the best which one of the following is the best way to do it. does one follow better formatting, does one have better performance?

```
  private int myfunc()
{
    int value=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if (i==2)
            value= 2;
    }

    return value;
}
```

or

```
 private int myfunc()
{

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if (i==2)
            return(2);
    }

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that these would have different performance? Did you measure them?

Comment: @GregHewgill I think he was asking if there was a performance difference (which obviously there is, though slight), rather than stating he thought there was.

Comment: @DaveNewton: It's not at all obvious that there is a performance difference. An average compiler (not even a good one) would likely optimise those functions to the same resulting assembly code.

Comment: @GregHewgill I certainly don't think it's obvious there is *no* performance implication, especially if we consider this a question about a pattern rather than this specific half dozen lines.  And certainly with a naive compiler or with optimization turned off, there would be.

Comment: @GregHewgill Default Java on Ubuntu doesn't, even for the contrived example (bytecode level; not JITted code).

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the `java` tag and thought this was C++. Bytecode compilers may generate different code, but I would expect the JIT compiler to end up with the same assembly code (but obviously this is harder to check).

Comment: This is a holy war and a micro optimization. Read Steve McConnell's Code Complete for qualitative arguments about both options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually on the edge of an old religious question in "structured programming": should you make your code have only one exit, or is it okay to have multiple exits?

In the C/C++/Java world, at least, it's most common to return as soon as you know the answer.  There are very tiny performance implications for that, but not nearly as much as there were 20 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the second approach.

Anyway you won't notice any performance difference in either ways if you correct the implementation of the first approach by 'break'ing the loop once you find the item you want.

It's a good programming practice not to declare variables unnecessarily. What you have done in the second approach is good in that way. And the second approach does not execute all the cycles in the for loop. So another good point.

If you do this for the first approach. Both will perform almost the same except declaring unwanted variable in the first approach. First approach gives some work for the garbage collector that doesn't happen in the second approach.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if (i==2)
        {
            value= 2;
            break;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my personal experience, the second one would be better because it will get to the return statement faster. It won't have to loop through i=3 through i=5, so it will run faster. It is also a little bit less confusing when you just return a value instead of keeping it for a while. This is important for when your code gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach does not compile as it is, you must add:

```
return 0;
```

as the last line of the method.

That said, the second method should be slightly faster, because there are less lines of code executed.

As a general rule, try to limit the number of return statements in method to a maximum of 6.

Note that the compiler is allowed to, and probably does, turn the first method into the second method in byte code (the variable `value` is not used after the loop, so the compiler is allowed to simply return it).

Comment: i will add that fix to the code

Answer (score 1):

As the above user said add return 0; so that the IDE will know if the program ran successively.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to become purist with your code, you will like `first approach`.

One reason is `continue`, `break` is not a good choice to write code. It is always possible to write code without using `continue` & `break`. Keeping your focus in the code regarding which part is doing exactly what and what is its scope.

Returning from a block is also possible, but it is same thing like using of `continue` & `break`.

Surely its not bad to `return` from a block. But returning from end of the method is good practice.

Comment: You make a number of assertions here, but I don't see anything to back them up.